# Diferencia entre $("#elemento") y $("#elemento")[0] Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de entender como funcionan **Javascript** y **Jquery**. Yo sé que esto:

```
var contenido = document.getElementById("contenido");
contenido.text("Hola desde Javascript");
```

Es lo mismo que esto:

```
var contenido = $("#contenido");
contenido.text("Hola desde Jquery");
```

Pero tengo entendido que esto:

```
var contenido = document.getElementById("contenido");
```

Es igual a esto en Jquery:

```
var contenido = $("#contenido")[0];
```

Por qué me agrega el texto sin el `[0]` al final ? Y si lo agrego no me muestra el mensaje, por qué si es lo mismo? En que momentos tengo que usar el `[0]` al final, un ejemplo ?

Comment: El [] se utiliza siempre para los array, si le agregas el [0] y no t muestra cuando le mandas texto es porque él está buscando asignar un texto a ese elemento el cual no existe en la vista porque tendrías a trabajarlo como array. Haz un "console.debug(contenido)" para q veas el elemento como lo está tratando. No t coloco ejemplo porque te estoy respondiendo desde mi celular. Disculpa.

Answer (score 3):

En el siguiente ejemplo verás que **no** es lo mismo.

```js
console.log($('#contenido') === document.getElementById('contenido') ); // false

console.log($('#contenido')[0] === document.getElementById('contenido') ); // true

console.log($('#contenido').get(0) === document.getElementById('contenido') ); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenido"></div>
```

Y se debe porque `jQuery` devuelve un `array`.

Si usas `[0]` o [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) tienes acceso al [DOM Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node).

Ejemplos prácticos:

```js
$('#contenido1').text('si funciona 1');

$('#contenido2').get(0).innerText = 'si funciona 2';

$(document.getElementById('contenido3')).text('si funciona 3');


// los proximos ejemplos no funcionan

$('#contenido').get(0).text('no funciona');

document.getElementById('contenido4').text('no funciona');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenido1"></div>
<div id="contenido2"></div>
<div id="contenido3"></div>
<div id="contenido4"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El método `$()` de *jQuery* devuelve un objeto dependiendo del parámetro que se le pase. Esto quiere decir que si le pasas un *ID* como selector únicamente te devolverá un objeto, ya que los *ID* en *HTML* no se pueden repetir. En cambio, si al método `$()` le pasas una clase o una etiqueta, al ser selectores que pueden repetirse, te devolverá un array con todos los objetos que correspondan con esa clase o esa etiqueta.

Te pongo un ejemplo:

**index.html**

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div class="miClase"></div>
<div class="miClase"></div>
```

**scripts.js**

```
$('#header').text('Hola'); // Devuelve un único objeto
$('.miClase').text('Mundo'); // Devuelve todos los objetos que tengan la clase indicada

/*
  Si quisiéramos aplicar el método text() solamente al primer elemento que tenga la clase
    miClase podríamos hacer referencia a él indicando su índice en el array que devuelve
    $('.miclase')
*/

$('.miClase')[0].text('Este es el primer div con .miClase');
```

Comment: Tengo un problema con lo que me explicó. Yo para acceder a todo el contenido de un formulario, tengo que ingresar `$("#form")[0]` para que funcione. O con JS, `document.getElementById("form")`. Por que tengo que ingresar ese `[0]` si solo tengo un solo formulario ? Además es un ID, por lo tanto es único.

Answer (score 0):

El [] se utiliza siempre para los array, si le agregas el [0] y no t muestra cuando le mandas texto es porque él está buscando asignar un texto a ese elemento el cual no existe en la vista porque tendrías a trabajarlo como array. Haz un "console.debug(contenido)" para q veas el elemento como lo está tratando. No t coloco ejemplo porque te estoy respondiendo desde mi celular. Disculpa.

Answer (score 0):

Al hacer un selector de *jQuery* a un elemento del *DOM*, la librería, crear un Objeto *jQuery*, que encierra el `[object HTML]`, inmediatamente ese objeto te expone una *API* a métodos más amigables y *Cross Browser* `.offset()`, `.animate()`, etc... Pero internamente está usando la misma *API* nativa **Vanilla** de *Javascript*.

Este objeto *jQuery* expone en el índice `0`, la referencia al `[object HTML]`, por si quieres ejecutar sobre el métodos de la *API* nativa de *Javascript*.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
var canvas = $('#canvas');
// error getContext() es un método de la API nativa,
// por lo tanto el objeto jQuery no tiene este método
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Solución:

```
var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
```